# Editing the Templates menu in TeXShop

Tags: templates, editors, texshop, mac

The Help menu of TeXShop, along with most of the web, advises me to access the  `~/Library/TeXShop/Templates` folder if I want to modify my Templates menu. I can't seem to find this folder however. I have tried accessing "Go -> `/Library/`" using the Finder menu but I cannot find any folder by the name of TeXShop there.

Any advice on this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: From the Go menu, hold down the Option key and choose "Library." The `~` refers to your home directory.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can also do `cd ~/Library/TeXShop/Templates && open .` from within Terminal.

Answer (score 6):

### From the Finder

The reason you didn't find the `~/Library` folder using the Go menu was that you left out the `~`.  This symbol denotes your "home" folder, whereas without it (what you typed `/Library` is the system Library folder.) Here's what the Go menu input should look like:

[image: Go menu]

### From inside TeXShop

But with recent versions of TeXShop there's a direct way to get to the `~/Library/TeXShop` folder in the TeXShop menu of the application:

[image: TeXShop menu]

### From the Terminal

From the command line you can type

```
cd ~/Library/TeXShop/Templates && open .
```

This means "change directory to `~/Library/TeXShop` and open `.` (the current directory)".  This will open a Finder window with the directory in it.

### Adding a new template

A template file is simply a `.tex` file that is stored in the Templates folder. Once you have added a file there, it will be immediately available in any new source window you open.